# Convert BBCode [IMG] to <img>

Tags: php, regex, image, preg-replace, bbcode

I'm using preg_replace to convert all BBCode to HTML but can't get img tags to work. Here is my code:

```
$search = array (
    '/(\[b\])(.*?)(\[\/b\])/m',
    '/(\[i\])(.*?)(\[\/i\])/m',
    '/(\[u\])(.*?)(\[\/u\])/m',
    '/(\[ul\])(.*?)(\[\/ul\])/m',
    '/(\[li\])(.*?)(\[\/li\])/m',
    '/(\[user=)(.*?)(\])(.*?)(\[\/user\])/m',
    '/(\[url=)(.*?)(\])(.*?)(\[\/url\])/m',
    '/(\[url\])(.*?)(\[\/url\])/m',
    '/(\[img=)(.*?)(\])(.*?)(\[\/img\])/m',
    '/(\[quote\])(.*?)(\[\/quote\])/m',
    '/(\[code\])(.*?)(\[\/code\])/m',
);

$replace = array (
    '<strong>$2</strong>',
    '<em>$2</em>',
    '<u>$2</u>',
    '<ul>$2</ul>',
    '<li>$2</li>',
    '<a href="../login/profile?u=$2" target="_blank">$2</a>',
    '<a href="$2" target="_blank">$4</a>',
    '<a href="$2" target="_blank">$2</a>',
    '<img src="$4"></img>',
    '<quote>$2</quote>',
    '<code>$2</code>'
);

$string = preg_replace($search, $replace, $string);
```

Right now it creates an image tag with the link in but adds `]` to the start and end of the link so it doesn't display the image correctly.

EDIT:

This is cause by me converting links to anchor tags and it's conflicting within the [img] BBCode.

```
$url = '/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/';

$string = preg_replace($url, '[url=$0]$0[/url]', $string);
```

Comment: Please show some unaltered sample input text, show the output that your code generates, then show your desired output.  Forging a solid question will be more helpful to future researchers and improve your chances of question upvotes (if you care about points).

Comment: Future readers shouldn't have to read the comments under my answer to understand the full story.  Please show that earlier replacement code.

Comment: I was wondering how would you do a check if they put a youtube url and then turned into into an iframe, I've been trying to figure it out but can't quite get it.

Comment: Sounds like a new question to me.  Please make sure you post a complete question with sample input, your best effort, and your exact desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several points to make:

- Change your pattern delimiters from `/` to `~` so that you don't have to escape the `/` characters that exist inside your pattern.
- Simply do not use capture groups on substrings that you don't intend to use.  In your patterns, none of the unwanted substrings need to be parenthetically wrapped to maintain pattern logic.
- The regex engine will only consider `]` to be the end of a character class if a character class is opened.  For this reason, I am not escaping any `]` characters.
- Because you aren't using any anchors (`^` or `$`), the `m` pattern modifier is needless.
- If you want case-insensitivity in your pattern, use the `i` pattern flag/modifier.
- After removing all of the excess capture groups, you only need to use `$1` in the replacement string.
- After processing the bbcoded urls, do a final sweep for any urls that are not already converted to html elements.  `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` "disqualifies" these unwanted substrings.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/G5lem))

```
$bbcodes = [
    'Look at this:https://www.example.com/example?ohyeah=sure#okay this is a raw link',
    'No attibute bbcode url: [url]http://example.com/x1[/url]',
    'A url with link and link text: [url=http://example.com/x2]x2[/url]',
    'Image with "ignorable" text: [IMG=sumpthing.jpg]sumpthing[/IMG]',
    'Image: [img=sumpinelse][/img]'
];

$search = array (
    // ...
    '~\[url=((?:ht|f)tps?://[a-z\d.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}/\S*?)](.*?)\[/url]~i',
    '~\[url]((?:ht|f)tps?://[a-z\d.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}/\S*?)\[/url]~i',
    // ...
    '~\[img=(.*?)].*?\[/img]~i',  // if you want the possibility of dot matching newlines, add s pattern modifier
    // ...
    '~(?:<a.*?</a>|<img.*?</img>)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\bhttps?://.+?(?=\s|$)~im'  // mop up any remaining links that are not bbtagged
);
$replace = array (
    // ...
    '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$2</a>',
    '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>',
    // ...
    '<img src="$1"></img>',
    // ...
    '<a href="$0" target="_blank">$0</a>',
);
var_export(preg_replace($search, $replace, $bbcodes));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Look at this:<a href="https://www.example.com/example?ohyeah=sure#okay" target="_blank">https://www.example.com/example?ohyeah=sure#okay</a> this is a raw link',
  1 => 'No attibute bbcode url: <a href="http://example.com/x1" target="_blank">http://example.com/x1</a>',
  2 => 'A url with link and link text: <a href="http://example.com/x2" target="_blank">x2</a>',
  3 => 'Image with "ignorable" text: <img src="sumpthing.jpg"></img>',
  4 => 'Image: <img src="sumpinelse"></img>',
)
```

Comment: I noticed my code is working, the problem is I have code to convert URLs to [url=][/url] first, this cause a glitch. My code looks like this `$url = '/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/';` `$string = preg_replace($url, '[url=$0]$0[/url]', $string);`

Comment: Well that pattern can be largely refined as well.  `$url_pattern = '~(?:ht|f)tps?://[a-z\d.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}/\S*?~i';`  This employs many of the pieces of advice in my answer.  But as you realize you need to not assume these urls are always for `[url]` tags.

Comment: Using that still causes the image to display as `<img src="[url=][/url]" title="">`, I want to be able to convert plain links to a clickable anchor but this conflicts with my [img] tag

Comment: No I want to be able to convert both the bbcode [url] into an anchor tag as well as just any link pasted without the bbcode tag. The bbcode [url] is to change what the link looks like instead of https://url. Converting the link into bbcode is causing a conflict within the [img] tag as it's converting the url from the src into [url] first.

Comment: Think I just managed to fix it by using this code `~(\s|^)(https?://.+?)(\s|$)~im`

Comment: I think you are likely to want wordboundaries (`\b`) for your case then.  `~\b(https?://.+?)\b~i` or for fringe cases: `~\b(https?://.+?)(?=\s|$)~im`  This page should reach a system-recognized resolution.  How would you like me to edit my answer so that it is acceptable?  Please edit your question so that it more accurately represents your issue.  Then I can edit my answer to precisely answer the posted question (instead of answering follow up comments).

Comment: My bad dude, I edited the question so you can change your answer and I'll mark correct.